# how to convert unix timestamp to datetime format in RESTful api service

Tags: java, spring

I am store unix timestamp in database like `1565170183785`, now I will provide api to client to invoke, how to convert unix timestamp in project scope? This is my controller code:

```
 @ApiOperation(value = "提转报表明细(转入转出明细)", tags = "数据报表")
    Response<PageBean<ReportTransDetailResponse>> transDetailPage(@RequestParam(required = true, value = "startDate") String startDate,
                                                                  @RequestParam(required = true, value = "endDate") String endDate,
                                                                  @RequestParam(required = false, value = "pageSize", defaultValue = "10") Integer pageSize,
                                                                  @RequestParam(required = true, value = "pageNum") Integer pageNum,
                                                                  @RequestParam(required = false, value = "transNo") String transNo,
                                                                  @RequestParam(required = true, value = "transType") Integer transType);
```

and this is part of my entity code:

```
@Data
@ApiModel
public class ReportTransDetailResponse implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 主键
     * report_trans_detail.id
     *
     * @mbggenerated
     */
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "主键")
    private Long id;

    /**
     * 交易流水号
     * report_trans_detail.trans_no
     *
     * @mbggenerated
     */
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "交易流水号")
    private Long transNo;

    /**
     * 创建时间
     * report_trans_detail.created_time
     *
     * @mbggenerated
     */
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "创建时间")
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",timezone = "GMT+8")
    private Long createdTime;

    /**
     * 更新时间
     * report_trans_detail.updated_time
     *
     * @mbggenerated
     */
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "更新时间")
    private Long updatedTime;

    /**
     * 交易时间
     * report_trans_detail.trans_time
     *
     * @mbggenerated
     */
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "交易时间")
    private Long transTime;

    /**
     * 用户ID
     * report_trans_detail.user_id
     *
     * @mbggenerated
     */
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "用户ID")
    private Long userId;




    /**
     * 创建者
     * report_trans_detail.creator
     *
     * @mbggenerated
     */
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "创建者")
    private Long creator;

    /**
     * 排序
     * report_trans_detail.sort
     *
     * @mbggenerated
     */
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "排序")
    private Integer sort;




}
```

I don't want to write code in every api,how to convert long timestamp to string format like "2019-08-09 10:01:54" in project scope? This is current response:

```
{
  "resultCode": "200",
  "statusCode": "200",
  "msg": "ok",
  "result": {
    "pagination": {
      "pageNum": 1,
      "pageSize": 1,
      "total": 88,
      "pages": 88,
      "hasPreviousPage": false,
      "hasNextPage": true
    },
    "list": [
      {
        "id": 88,
        "transNo": 147778468896047100,
        "createdTime": 1565840892577,
        "updatedTime": 1565840892577,
        "transTime": 1565840892577,
        "userId": 15571,
        "userName": "嗨金金",
        "transAmount": 1000000,
        "creator": 15571,
        "sort": 0,
        "deleted": 0,
        "platform": 1,
        "status": 1,
        "transType": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  "validationErrors": null,
  "costTime": 0
}
```

this is format I want:

```
{
  "resultCode": "200",
  "statusCode": "200",
  "msg": "ok",
  "result": {
    "pagination": {
      "pageNum": 1,
      "pageSize": 1,
      "total": 88,
      "pages": 88,
      "hasPreviousPage": false,
      "hasNextPage": true
    },
    "list": [
      {
        "id": 88,
        "transNo": 147778468896047100,
        "createdTime": "2016-08-9 10:01:54",
        "updatedTime": "2016-08-9 10:01:54",
        "transTime": "2016-08-9 10:01:54",
        "userId": 15571,
        "userName": "嗨金金",
        "transAmount": 1000000,
        "creator": 15571,
        "sort": 0,
        "deleted": 0,
        "platform": 1,
        "status": 1,
        "transType": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  "validationErrors": null,
  "costTime": 0
}
```

I am trying to avoid write convert code in every api function,Spring Framework is what I am using now.

Comment: Please, add controller code snippet.

Comment: Have you tried to write an interceptor to modify response ?

Comment: Something, between your database and the JSON generation, should transform the timestamp into an Instant. Jackson itself will transform an Instant to an ISO-8601 string. The closer to the database, the best, because you should really use Instants in your own code rather than longs.

Comment: Replace `private Long createdTime` by `private Instant createdTime`. And remove your JsonFormat annotation: stick to the standard ISO format and UTC.